# Как можно остановить компиляцию программы на этапе препроцессинга?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компиляция, препроцессор

Как можно получить код, который получается после этапа препроцессинга программы? Как это можно сделать с помощью опций в командной строке?

Comment: Т.е. получить листинг после обработки препроцессором? Используйте соответствующие опции компилятора. У вас какой?

Comment: компилятор MSVC, получить файл, который препроцессор обработал и передаёт компилятору

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Минимально задаете в командной строке параметр `/E` — вывод того, что получилось, на экран.

Если зададите `/P /FiИмя_Файла` — то будет выведено в указанный вами файл.

Полный список опций для препроцессора легко получить, запустив в командной строке `cl /?`

```
                              -ПРЕПРОЦЕССОР-

/AI<каталог> добавить к пути поиска сборок
/FU<файл> обязательное использование сборки или модуля 
/C не удалять комментарии               
/D<имя>{=|#}<текст> задать макроопределение
/E вывод сообщений в stdout             /EP вывод сообщений в stdout, без #line
/P вывод сообщений в файл               /Fx добавить внесенный код в файл
/FI<файл> задать имя обязательно включаемого файла
/U<имя> удалить встроенное макроопределение
/u удалить все встроенные макроопределения
/I<каталог> добавить в путь поиска включаемых файлов
/X пропустить "standard places"         
/PH создает #pragma file_hash во время предварительной обработки
/PD выводить все определения макросов   
/Fi: <файл> задание имени файла препроцессора
```